# MaterialSkin.dll запуск программу с ней. C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет!

У меня проблема, я использую скин Material от гугла.
Для работы приложения он обязательно должен быть в папке с программой, так вот, я хотел сделать так, чтобы вдруг что, если его нет он скачивался, делал так:

Создал новую форму, пустую, где нет элементов из этого скина, чтобы при запуска программы, открывалась эта форма и скачивала MaterialSkin.dll с сайта к примеру, в папку(ну или не скачивала если он и так есть, а просто перекидывало на некст форму), проверяла опять если ли на этот раз файл и уже тогда перекидывало на некст форму.
Дело в том, что программа всё равно не запускается без MaterialSkin.dll, хотя на вот этой первой форме ничего нет из этого скина

Comment: Соберите все в один .exe файл и радуйтесь жизни. Ну а так, как у вас вообще запустится проект без зависимой .dll?

Comment: Либо делайте динамическое связывание библиотек во время исполнения программы, либо оно вам не надо, т.к. при статическом связывании во время компиляции запуск приложения без всех необходимых библиотек просто невозможен, в чем вы уже сами убедились. Как альтернатива, но лично я против таких решений для всего подряд - отдельное микро-приложение или скрипт для запуска основного приложения которое и будет проверять целостность набора файлов основного приложения и докачивать нужное.